# Copy array & paste it using a Loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

**TARGET**

I have to copy a range of data and paste it into another Spreadsheet / Sheet.

**CONTEXT**

I managed to build the script in a very basic mode. Below these lines you will see my code.

In my code I created the variable Personas and I saved the range "A2;D5" into Personas. Then I pasted that data in the range "F2:I2" in that same sheet.

**QUESTION**

I'd like to improve that Loop because this is a very simple example with only 4 values (4 columnas = A:D). If I had to deal with 30 columns I should enter 30 lines of code – one for each column.

How could I handle it in a simpler way?

Thanx

```
function copyAndPasteIt(){

  var ssObjects = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Objects')
  var personas = ssObjects.getRange("A2:D5").getValues()

  Logger.log(personas)

  for(i=0; i<4; i++){

        ssObjects.getRange((2+i), 6).setValue(personas [i][0])        
        ssObjects.getRange((2+i), 7).setValue(personas [i][1])    
        ssObjects.getRange((2+i), 8).setValue(personas [i][2])
        ssObjects.getRange((2+i), 9).setValue(personas [i][3])

  }

}
```

Comment: `setValue(value)` is not the only method of writing a value. In particular, try `setValues(object[][])`. You will have to use one of the alternate method signatures for `getRange` - the ones which allow you to specify the number of rows and columns will be most useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a loop for each cell, you can get a data range to copy with 'getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)':
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns

And then get a range where you want paste the data:

```
sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns).setValues(array);
```

Here you can find an example with the different (in terms of performance too) to write one cell at a time, one row at a time or all data at once:

http://www.appsscript.it/articoli/scrivere-dati-su-uno-spreadsheet-in-modo-performante-con-google-apps-script/